# Why is there ?url= query param added to ISR routes with Nuxt3?

Tags: vercel, nuxt3, pre-rendering

In production (Vercel), all my ISR routes have a `?url=` query param added, why?

`https://website.com/pages/foo` become `https://website.com/pages/foo?url=/pages/foo` when I refresh the page (nothing when I navigate in the website)

This seems to only happen with isr routes in prod and I can't find anything related in the doc.

My nuxt.config.ts

```
routeRules: {
  "/**": { prerender: true },
  "/pages/**": { isr: 60 },
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug on vercel-edge preset with isr and swr

I removed `"preset": "vercel-edge"` from nitro.config.js